# ng-click is not triggering in span inside textbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I've searched this for a while but i was not able to find any answer to it.

My problem is quite simple, i have a glyphicon span inside a textbox but i want this icon to clean the textbox on click and for some reason ng-click is not triggering.

I believe that's something above the span covering it but i was not able to find anything to make this icon 'clickable'. I'm using `has-feedback` and `form-control-feedback` bootstrap classes maybe this is the problem as well...

Here's the code:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
   <input type="text" class="form-control rounded"
                      placeholder="Search" title="Looking for something?" id="searchTxt" ng-model="vm.searchQuery"/>
   <span ng-click="vm.clearSearch()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback cursor-pointer" style="color: black; font-size: 20px"></span>
</div>
```

Here's a plunker of the problem:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ks33j3x9XWkJkeSpn90w?p=preview

As you can see i got a button beside the textbox that clicks normally, but the span inside it doesn't. I've tried a lot of things, like z-index, wrapping the span in a button, tried to see where the button is, but with no luck on making it clickable.

Comment: Remove `pointer-event:none`. Check [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/2ZMWQC5Dedt4Y56LGMdP?p=preview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add "pointer-events: auto; cursor: pointer;" to your style class in span